# Pass parameter through php vaiable from form to another php file

Tags: php, forms, parameter-passing

I have next html form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="frames1.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="uri1" class="control-label">URL:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" id="uri1" placeholder="www.ejemplo.com">
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Visualizar" />
                    </div>
</form>
```

I want to pass the value from textbox "uri1" to a php variable.

Thats my frames1.php:

```
<?php
 $uriValue = $_GET["uri1"];
?>

<script>
var uri = '<?php echo $uriValue;?>';
alert(uri);
</script>
```

But the system shows me "", not the value I put on the textbox in the form just before.

How can pass the value from the textbox to read on the php file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using method as post in form co change this to

```
<?php
    $uriValue = $_POST["uri1"];
 ?>

<script>
    var uri = '<?php echo $uriValue;?>';
    alert(uri);
</script>
```

and also add name attribute to your field. `name="uri1"`

that is,

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="frames1.php" method="post">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="uri1" class="control-label">URL:</label>
             <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" id="uri1" name="uri1" placeholder="www.ejemplo.com">
              </div>
      </div>                  
      <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Visualizar" />
       </div>
</form>
```

[Here](http://code.runnable.com/Vh5BMwy9ZXZaqDnn/post-in-php) is the working link.

Comment: It continues failing. It's not reading the value where I puts on the the form. It shows the string from the uri variable.

Comment: firstly replace the get with post and also dont forget to add the name attribute.

Comment: I have done everything you says me and not working. I don`t understand if is an simple example to work with php and forms POST.

Comment: in freames1.php, `print_r($_POST();`, and see what you r getting.

Comment: I have added full code. Its working for me. chack once.

Comment: could you pass me a link to see it? I don`t know what more to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92255/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-jaime-menendez-llana).

Answer (score 1):

You send a form by `POST` but in your `frames1.php` file, you try to get the content with `$_GET`. So what you have to do is just change `GET`to `POST`, so it looks like

```
<?php
   $uriValue = $_POST["uri1"];
?>
```

Also a bigger problem is, that your input doesn't have a name, the parameter can only be referenced by the name, not by the ID. So your input should look like that:

```
<input type="text" id="uri1" name="uri1" placeholder="www.ejemplo.com">
```

Comment: Continues failing... The value which pass is an empty value

Comment: Did you change both? So using `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` and giving your input a name?

Comment: By the way, why are you using a `modal footer` in your form, while you have no modal at all?

Comment: Anyway, if it doesn't work yet, you should try some debugging, so first look in your network explorer, if the value is really set. You can do that (in most browsers) by pressing F12, then you go to Network. There you can click on the page and see which data was transmitted via the form. If it's in there, please try to echo the variable first, before "transfering" to javascript, and tell us the result

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Finally I change the action from the form passing the url to a new html file, so in that one I parse the uri which it let's me to do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

There are one mistake in HTML as well as PHP code, You have to give name to the input field's. When form is submitted to the server then It will recognize fetch values using HTML Input Field names, and If your posted form in HTML, then you have to use same method to get the values.

Try to replace bellow code with your code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="frames1.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="uri1" class="control-label">URL:</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input type="text" name="uri1" id="uri1" placeholder="www.ejemplo.com">
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" value="Visualizar" />
                    </div>
</form>
```

Coming to your frames1.php:

```
<?php
 $uriValue = $_POST["uri1"];
?>

<script>
var uri = '<?php echo $uriValue;?>';
alert(uri);
</script>
```

Let me know still not resolved.

Diff in HTML file is:

```
 <input type="text" name="uri1" id="uri1" placeholder="www.ejemplo.com">
```

you didn't mention the name, then server will not recognize the element.

In PHP:
Your using POST method but your getting the values using _GET[], both are incompatible methods. So you will not get the values which are submitted by the form

```
<?php
 $uriValue = $_POST["uri1"];
?>
```

Comment: @nameless, Updated my ans with explanation

Answer (score 0):

You have set form `method="post"`.

Therefore, after your form gets submitted, the value should be:

```
$uriValue = $_POST["uri1"];
```

Not

```
$uriValue = $_GET["uri1"];
```

**Solutions:**

1) Either change your form method `method="post"` to get your existing code working.

2) Change `$uriValue = $_GET["uri1"];` to `$uriValue = $_POST["uri1"];`